# (SAS) Option Implied volatility calculation using proc model or whatever procedure

Tags: sas

I am a beginner to use SAS.
I want to calculate an implied volatility.

My dataset looks like below

Option_code / put_call_idx / underlying_price / dividend_yield / maturity / option_premium / strike_price /  etc.

```
A / "PUT" / 1000 / 0.5 / 13 / 5 / 980 / .......
B / "CALL" / 1000 / 0.5 / 13 / 10 / 990 / .......
```

Each row has different option's information so I want to have my final 
dataset after solving implied volatility having the form below:

```
A / "PUT" / 1000 / 0.5 / 13 / ...... / **0.15 (IV for option A)**
B / "CALL" / 1000 / 0.5 / 13 / ...... / **0.18 (IV for option B)**
```

My messy code looks like this

---

```
proc model data = INPUT noprint;

exogenous ksp200 ksp200_div ttm strike_prc rf;

endogenous iv;

n_1 = log(ksp200 * exp((rf - ksp200_div) * (ttm/250)) / strke_price

.... other Black-Scholes Formula input  .......

0 = abs(model price - market price)

solve iv / maxiter = 100 converge = 0.1 out = iv_root;
by option_code;

run;
```

---

After executing some rows has right solutions but with error messages
meaning that some observation don't have solution after Newton method iteration.

I think the data from actual exchange quotes the error message doesn't make sense to me. So my messy code or method is by definition wrong? or is there any alternative to calculating implied volatility?

let me know some cite or reference page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt with this issue a lot.  Often time option quotes are stale and do not make sense.  When you attempt to solve for the implied volatility, the solution hits the bound at IV=0.  For example, a simple call is quoted at $5, but is $6 in the money.  You should check for values that do not make sense and find a way to handle them.

I like your `PROC MODEL` method  Personally, I would put these into my own functions using `PROC FCMP` and use the Data Step.  There is a `SOLVE` function available in `FCMP` that can find the root for you.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.options;

/*Taken from Wikipedia - BS with a continous dividend*/
function optPrc(type $, K,S,q,r,ttm,vol);
    d1 = (1/(vol*sqrt(ttm)))*(log(S/K)+(r-q+.5*vol**2)*ttm);
    d2 = d1-(vol*sqrt(ttm));
    F=S*exp((r-q)*ttm);
    ert = exp(-r*ttm);
    prc = .;
    if upcase(substr(type,1,1)) = "C" then 
        prc = ert*(F*cdf('NORMAL',d1,0,1)-K*cdf('NORMAL',d2,0,1));
    else if upcase(substr(type,1,1)) = "P" then
        prc = ert*(K*cdf('NORMAL',-d2,0,1)-F*cdf('NORMAL',-d1,0,1));

    return(prc);

endsub;

/*IV Solver*/
function opt_iv(type $, K,S,q,r,ttm,opt_prc);

    iv = .;
    prc = optPrc(type , K,S,q,r,ttm,1e-8);
    if opt_prc < prc then do;
        PUT "ERROR: Option Price out of bounds" opt_prc= prc= "at 0 vol";
    end;
    else do;
        array opts[5] initial abconv relconv maxiter status
                        (.5   .001   1.0e-6  100     -1);

        iv = solve("optPrc",opts, opt_prc, type , K, S, q, r, ttm, .);
        if status ^= 0 then 
            PUT "ERROR: Problem Solving." STATUS=;
    end;

    return (iv);
endsub;

run;
quit;

options cmplib=(work.fns);

data test;
Type = "PUT";
Underlying = 1000;
Div_Yield = 0.5;
Maturity = 13;
Opt_Prc=5;
Strike=980;
output;
Type = "CALL";
Underlying = 1000;
Div_Yield = 0.5;
Maturity = 13;
Opt_Prc=10;
Strike=990;
output;

/*This obviously is bad - call is $10 in the money, but quoted at 5*/
Type = "CALL";
Underlying = 1000;
Div_Yield = 0;
Maturity = 13;
Opt_Prc=5;
Strike=990;
output;


/*This obviously is put - put is $10 in the money, but quoted at 5*/
Type = "PUT";
Underlying = 1000;
Div_Yield = 0;
Maturity = 13;
Opt_Prc=5;
Strike=1010;
output;
run;


data test2;
set test;

iv= opt_iv(type, Strike,Underlying,Div_Yield/100,0.005,Maturity/250,Opt_Prc);
run;
```